# Python3 Add "" to a variable print(value) that is a simple name

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with the name as the keys. So, if I do:

```
print(GPS)
```

it will print:

```
Adam
```

that is just an example, but I want it to print:

```
"Adam"
```

With the quotes. and I do this is a loop so it prints every key in my dict that is a name. I cant seem to be able to put `""` around it within the print statment because if I try

```
print("GPS")
```

it simply prints

```
GPS
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason for your problem is that GPS is a variable name, so it prints the content of the variable, which is a string. When you encase it in quotes, you instead give the literal string `"GPS"`.

You need to concatenate the strings together. E.g:

```
print('"'+GPS+'"')
```

Note my use of single quotes to contain the strings, so the double quote characters didn't conflict. If you wanted to use double quotes, you would need to escape the double quotes that are a part of the string, for example:

```
print("\""+GPS+"\"")
```

In python,  a backslash escapes the double quotes character, so it is treated as content of the string, not an end to it.

For more complicated strings, you might want to use the [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#format-examples) function:

```
print('"{0}"'.format(GPS))
```

It is also worth noting that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends `lowercase_with_underscores` for variable names, so `GPS` would normally denote a class, and `gps` might be more suitable.

Comment: Genious!! :) Thank you I been stuck on this for like 50 minutes :( I runned a marathon through google and python docs but apparently I missed it. Thank you so muhc.

Answer (score 0):

Type a single statement that produces the following output.
Output the value of the variable user_num, not the literal 35. Hint: Typing 'Quantity of books is 35' is a common mistake, as is 'Quantity of books is user_num'. See above section for how to output a variable's value.

Quantity of books is 35

Comment: no idea how to even start this all the things ive tried doesnt work such as print('Quantity of book is', user_num